# Prompt for permission shows only "DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, manifest

I wanted to start with compose, since I've never used it, but I got stuck at permissions, as I no longer can pick permission from the manifest, as I used to. Now, the only one "permission" that I can pick is:

```
DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION
```

How I can add here permissions like coarse/fine location? They are added to the manifest, but still I can't pick them.